# Query with multiple conditions on a nested entry in MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, querying, embedded-documents, nosql

I have a Document `A` that contains a ListField `b` of a particular 
type EmbeddedDocument `B`, which have two StringFields `x` and `y`.

```
class B(EmbeddedDocument):
    x = StringField()
    y = StringField()

class A(Document):
    b = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(B))
```

Let's populate them first:

```
b1 = B(x="x1", y="y1")
b2 = B(x="x2", y="y2")
a = A(b=[b1, b2])
a.save()
```

I want to search for an instance of `A` that contains a particular
entry `B` with values `x=x1` and `y=y1`.

I tried to build a query with two `contains`, one for each value.

```
A.objects(b__x__contains="x1", b__y__contains="y1")
[<A: A object>]
```

The success case works. The problem is that the conditions are 
independent, then they can match different entries of list `b`:

```
A.objects(b__x__contains="x1", b__y__contains="y2")
[<A: A object>]
```

Is there a way, in MongoEngine, to ensure that these two conditions
will be applied in the same entry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of I understand your question. You could try `$elemMatch`

Eg: `Find Query`

```
db.A.findOne(
   {
     b : {$elemMatch : {"x":"x1", "y":"y1"}}
   }
);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Afil, thanks a lot for you quick answer! I would like to do it preferably through MongoEngine. If I couldn't get it done, it's great to remember that I can make a MongoDB call at MongoEngine and use $elemMatch. Very best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an issue [#379](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/379) at MongoEngine Github.

$elemMatch was mapped to `field__match`.

So the success case works:

```
A.objects(b__match={"x": "x1", "y": "y1"})
[<A: A object>]
```

And wrong case one fail:

```
A.objects(b__match={"x": "x2", "y": "y1"})
[]
```

Thanks a lot Afil to show me that what I need was equivalent to $elemMatch.